# why Rudin has been taken $\mu(S_n^c)=0$ and why $\mu(E^c)=0 ?$

Tags: measure-theory

I have some  confusion in  **Rudin RCA Book**

My confusion have been marked  in red box , given  below

[image]

**My attempt**  : Here its given that  $S_n$ is the set   on $f_n$ and $\mu(S_n^c)=0$

Then it will  implies  $ S_n$ is infinite and $S_n^c$ is finite

Then  it   should be  $\int_S \varphi d\mu  > \infty$

Another  its given that $E= \{ x \in S : \varphi(x)  < \infty\}$ this implies $E $ is  finite set and $\mu(E^c)=\infty$ since $E^c= \{ x \in S : \varphi(x)  > \infty\}$

**My doubt** : $1.$ why Rudin has been taken   $\mu(S_n^c)=0$ ? what is the  logics behind this ?

$2.$why  $\mu(E^c)=0 ?$

Comment: $1$: By hypothesis $f_n$ is defined almost everywhere (a.e.), so by definition that set on which it is **not** defined has measure $0$; $S_n^c$ is that set. $2$: $E$ is **not** finite: $E$ is the set of points $x$ such that $\varphi(x)$ is finite.

Comment: You need to explain your attempt more. $\mu(S_n^c) = 0$ doesn't mean that $S_n^c$ is finite, for starters. Second, $S_n$ being infinite doesn't make $\int_S \phi d \mu > \infty$ (whatever that means). You may need to review the previous chapters before proceeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a.e. means *almost everywhere*, so when something happens a.e. we're saying that the set where it doesn't happen has zero measure.

Since each $f_n$ is defined a.e. on $X$, if we denote $S_n$ as the set where $f_n$ is defined, then the set where it doesn't happen (where $f_n$ isn't defined) is $S_n^\mathsf c$, so $\mu(S_n^\mathsf c)=0$.

Now consider $S=\bigcap S_n$ and $E=\{x\in S:\varphi(x)=\sum|f_n(x)|<\infty\}$. Note that $x\in E^\mathsf c\Leftrightarrow x\notin E\Leftrightarrow x\notin S\lor (x\in S\land \varphi(x)=\infty)\Leftrightarrow x\in S^\mathsf c\lor(x\in S\land\varphi(x)=\infty)\Leftrightarrow x\in\bigcup S_n^\mathsf c\,\lor(x\in S\land\varphi(x)=\infty)$

so $E^\mathsf c=\big(\bigcup S_n^\mathsf c\big)\sqcup\{x\in S:\varphi(x)=\infty\}$ (the union is clearly disjoint, since the first part is $S^\mathsf c$ and the second part is in $S$).

Since $\mu(\bigcup S_n^\mathsf c)=\mu(S^\mathsf c)=0$, then $\mu(E^\mathsf c)=\mu\big(\bigcup S_n^\mathsf c\big)+\mu\big(\{x\in S:\varphi(x)=\infty\}\big)=\mu\big(\{x\in S:\varphi(x)=\infty\}\big)$.

Now imagine $\mu(E^\mathsf c)\neq0\Rightarrow\mu(E^\mathsf c)>0$. Then, since $\mu(S^\mathsf c)=0$ we have that $\mu\big(\{x\in S:\varphi(x)=\infty\}\big)>0$, and knowing that $\mu\big(\{x\in S:\varphi(x)=\infty\}\big)\subseteq S$ and $\phi(x)\ge0$ on $S$,

$$\int_S\varphi\,\text{d}\mu\ge\int_{\{x\in S:\varphi(x)=\infty\}}\varphi\,\text{d}\mu=\infty$$ since $\varphi(x)=\infty$ on $\{x\in S:\varphi(x)=\infty\}$ and $\mu\big(\{x\in S:\varphi(x)=\infty\}\big)>0$.

Therfore $\displaystyle\int_S\varphi\,\text{d}\mu=\infty$, which is a contradiction, so we conclude that $\mu(E^\mathsf c)=0$.